# When I measure VM1 at the output pin 3 of NE555 U1 in the schematic below, it differs from VM2 at the control pin 5 at NE555 U2 - why?

Tags: 555, siren

I temporarily replaced C1 with a 100uF electrolytic capacitor so that the oscillations in pitch from high to low were slow enough to allow me to take voltage readings at VM1 and VM2.

**For IC 555 U1 at pin 3**:

- During high pitch sound: VM1 = 0.04V
- During low pitch sound: VM1 = 4.00V

**For IC 555 U2 at pin 5**:

- During high pitch sound: VM2 = 2.41V
- During low pitch sound: VM2 = 3.45V

I thought that an input at pin 5 of a 555 over-rode 2/3 Vcc but I can't see why the output (pin 3) of U1 changes.
Also, I want to calculate the frequency of the high and low pitch sounds but I don't know which set of meter readings to use - those at pin 3 of U1 or those at pin 5 of U2.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNwCGx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

No, it doesn't "override" the default 2/3 Vcc at pin 5. Pin 5 is connected directly to the string of three internal 5 kΩ resistors in the 555, so your external R4 becomes part of a voltage divider in conjunction with them.

As to which voltage to use to calculate the frequency, it should be obvious that U2 can only "see" the voltage VM2, so that's the voltage you should use. Keep in mind that changing the upper threshold at pin 5 also affects the default 1/3 Vcc trigger threshold — it will be half of whatever the pin 5 voltage is.

Comment: I am completely self-taught and still rather new so my questions might seem a bit simple. How does one calculate the voltage at the 1st (i.e. what was once 2/3Vcc) and 2nd (what was once 1/3 Vcc) comparators given that the external R4 has now becomes part of the 5k ohm voltage divider and looks parallel to one of them and also provides an additional voltage source? I cannot find anywhere on-line how to approach a voltage divider problem with both one additional parallel resistor and 2 voltage supplies. Am I approaching the problem wrongly?

Answer (score 1):

See internal diagram (from TI datasheet); if nothing or only a capacitor is connected to pin 5, the flip-flop will be set when TRIG is below 1/3 of Vcc, and reset when THRES is over 2/3 Vcc.

[image]

Is astable operation, tH is the time to charge capacitor C from 1/3 Vcc to 2/3 Vcc through R=Ra+Rb. The C voltage  will follow this equation:

$$Vc(t)=(Vcc-\frac{1}{3}Vcc)(1-e^{-\frac{t}{RC}})+\frac{1}{3}Vcc$$

The time tH when Vc = 2/3 Vcc will result in 0.693*(Ra+Rb)C, as shown in the datasheet.

The tL will be calculated as the discharge of C through R=Rb, from 2/3 Vcc to 1/3 Vcc:

$$Vc(t) = \frac{2}{3}Vcc e^{-\frac{t}{RC}}$$

it will give 0.693*RbC

[image]

You can force the control voltage of U2 if you connect directly U1 pin 3 to U2 pin 5 (R4=0), but with a control voltage of 0.04 V, U2 comparators will probably not work, and it will not oscillate. The value of R4 will determine the control voltage of U2.

When you change control voltage (pin 5), previous calculations are not applicable. As stated in your question, U1 output will be 4 V at high level, and 0.04 at low level, practically 0 V.

[image]

To calculate the influence in control voltage of U2, you can calculate the currents of both path, 2 equations with 2 variables:

\$Vcc    = i1R1 + (i1+i2)(R2+R3)\$

\$U1outH = i2R4 + (i1+i2)(R2+R3)\$

From these you can get:

\$Vcc - i1R1 = U1outH - i2R4\$

Replace i1 or i2 in the first equation and you will get currents values. The control voltage will be:

\$Vcont  = (i1+i2)(R2+R3)\$

In your diagram, you have to use 2.41 V and the half (because of the resistor divider, 1.205 V) for the final and initial voltages of Vc in equations to obtain charge tH, and swap these voltages to obtain tL of discharge. Add this times and calculate inverse to know frequency when pin5 of U2 is 2.41.

Charge (R=R6+R5): \$Vc(tH)=(Vcc-1.205)(1-e^{-\frac{tH}{RC}}) + 1.205 = 2.41\$

Discharge (R=R6): \$Vc(tL)=2.41(e^{-\frac{tL}{RC}}) = 1.205\$

Repeat this calculation with 3.45 V and the half (1.725) to know frequency and this level:

Charge (R=R6+R5): \$Vc(tH)=(Vcc-1.725)(1-e^{-\frac{tH}{RC}}) + 1.725 = 3.45\$

Discharge (R=R6): \$Vc(tL)=3.45(e^{-\frac{tL}{RC}}) = 1.725\$

Comment: I had actually used the formula V(t) = Vf + (Vi - Vf)e-t/RC using 2.41 during charging but didn't use 1.205V because I hadn't realized what Dave Tweed had stated in his answer. From your functional block diagram I can now see why R4 affects 1/3Vcc as well as 2/3Vcc.

Answer (score 1):

The resistor divider inside the 555, that sets threshold and trigger potentials, consists of three resistors of 5kΩ in series (or 100kΩ for CMOS versions of the 555). The ends of this chain are connected to the power terminals of the IC:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fl7vEG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There are a couple of ways you can calculate how R4 in your schematic will influence this divider.

Since the the left end of R4, node X, is connected to the output of the previous timer IC, which is either high or low, the potential there is either \$V_X = V_{CC}\$ or \$V_X = 0\$.

One approach is to treat the two scenarios as follows: When \$V_X = V_{CC}\$, R4 is effectively in parallel with R1. When \$V_X = 0\$, R4 is effectively in parallel with R2 + R3. These are pictured here:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLk8QB.png)</sup>

These simplify to the equivalents shown below, which are trivial to analyse, but I've cheated and shown the simulated control pin potentials \$V_Y\$ when \$V_{CC}=+5V\$:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEC4KL.png)</sup>

These correspond reasonably closely to your measured values, but the discrepancy is sufficient to raise questions. The answers may be related to the fact that the 8Ω speaker is drawing way too much current from the output of U2. A typical 555 output is quite capable of sinking or sourcing 200mA or so (which you can find stated in the "Recommended Operating Conditions" table of the [555 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ne555.pdf)), but the speaker is demanding much more than that. If the 555 could comply, U2 output current \$I_{SPK}\$ would be:

$$ I_{SPK} = \pm \frac{5V}{8\Omega} = 630mA $$

The 555 output cannot do that, and consequently the signal across the speaker will be significantly less than 5V peak-to-peak. And current will likely be closer to ±300mA. Eventually this will damage the IC, and you should aim to reduce current to 200mA.

The required total resistance between a 5V potential difference that would pass 200mA is:

$$ R_{SPK} + R_{EXTRA} = \frac{5V}{200mA} = 25\Omega $$

That means you should place at least \$R_{EXTRA} = 17\Omega\$ in series with the speaker, and make it beefy because it will be dissipating power \$P\$:

$$ P = I^2R = (200mA)^2 \times 17\Omega = 0.7W $$

That still doesn't explain why the voltages you measured aren't quite as high as those I predicted above. I suspect that your power supply voltage is dipping under 5V with such a heavy current demand from the circuit. This would also explain why the output of U1 is under 5V. Perhaps by implementing that \$R_{EXTRA}\$ correction measure, the supply will fluctuate less.

Also, you really need to place a 100nF (ceramic) capacitor across the supply pins of U2, right at the pins themselves, as close as you can put it. This is called "supply decoupling", and will help the IC get the current it needs as it needs it. It will also help prevent that IC from causing power supply dips that all the other elements sharing that same supply must endure.

The second way to predict the control pin potentials that will be present due to R4 is with a [thevenin equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9venin%27s_theorem) circuit. The three-resistor-divider can be replaced by its equivalent:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0EKjc.png)</sup>

Now you can redraw the circuit including R4, but with this equivalent replacing the three other resistors:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fInRzz.png)</sup>

Thevenin equivalency simplifies the analysis enormously, and as you can see, the results for \$V_Y\$ are the same.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. But given that pin 3 of U1 is either outputting 0.04V or 4.00V, why are you stating that "...the left end of R4, node X, is connected to the output of the previous timer IC, which is either high or low, the potential there is either VX=VCC or VX=0." - isn't Vx = 4.00V or 0.04V and not simply 5V or 0V?

Comment: @JR Those calculations are based on U1 output being very close to 5V or 0V, as they ***should*** be. The only reason I can think of why that output would be only 4V is if the supply is also 4V, and not the assumed 5V, which as I said is probably due to the loudspeaker. You should also measure \$V_{CC}\$ to confirm this.

Comment: @JR  Also, be aware that as long as the loudspeaker is drawing large currents at high frequency, your multimeter readings are not very meaningful. Measure all voltages *without* the loudspeaker in place, so the supply can "keep up", and maintain a steady \$V_{CC}=+5V\$. I'm sure you'll find 555 output potentials reaching much closer to +5V, and \$V_Y\$ is much closer to the values shown in my answer.

Comment: @JR While testing voltages, just remove it. Also compare \$V_{CC}\$ (power supply voltage) both with and without speaker.

Comment: I simply removed the speaker and now the voltages at pin 3 of U1 are 0.12V and 3.78V i.e the output is even worse. Also pin 5 of U2 is 2.20V and 3.21V. The Vcc from the supply is an unsteady 4.8V (i.e it's oscillating between 4.94V & 4.75V more quickly than the oscillations at pin 3 of U1 and pin 5 of U2). Also I added a 104 ceramic cap. at pin 5 of U2 - do I need to do it at pin 8 also? Is this info. of any use?

Comment: @JR It tells me you have serious power supply problems. It's deeper than a comment can answer, but try the circuit with 4 AA cells or something. Keep the supply leads short, put decoupling caps across both ICs, etc. The usual stuff. You absolutely must sort out the supply issues before you can do anything further. Maybe try a USB battery bank, or some other 5V supply; anything to replace the existing supply, just for testing.